# Linking DocuSign Pages to clients in bulk

Tags: docusignapi

We have clients who sign signature pages for tax returns and other files alike. We will have thousands of these pages in a pdf or in a zip file. We are trying to upload these files to our AWS S3 bucket and want to know which user matches which document link. From here, we will connect the completed signature pages onto their account on our website. We want to know the optimal way of being able to solve this problem since it is in bulk and doing it by automation is way better. I am wondering if the docusign API already has some function(s) to help us with this.

So far, I've already played with the rest API quick startcode examples, and the PHP Auth Grant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do all of that with the API, but you have some decisions to make:
do you want the documents to be store in DocuSign or AWS?
How do you control access/permissions to the documents?

If you store them in DocuSign - that implies that only those with access to the DocuSign account (have user/password for DocuSign) can view the even if linked from an AWS site.

Comment: I would say AWS then because we want users to be able to view their own signed documents on their accounts. So in theory, users should have only access to their own signed documents. Since you mentioned that is part of the API capability, could you expand further on that?

Comment: Also, just to clarify, if we want to link the official docusign links in our website to the user such as the completed document, that would not be possible as only those with access to the docusign account can view it?

Comment: so far I've seen like matching templates, but was this the method you're referring to in your post?

Comment: it seems to me what you are looking for is uploading all your completed documents to AWS. Look at Connect for the webhook and then the API to GET a completed doc. Let me add some links

Comment: Getting a document - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get

Comment: Could you expand a little bit on the Connect and webhooks? I'm not quite sure where to go from there. Thanks for all the help so far by the way.

Comment: You can add a listener to your DocuSign account such that every time an envelope is complete - you get a call from DocuSign to your wevserver with the information. You can then use this information to get the completed document (see my second link) and upload it to AWS